# GZIP IIS caused images to dissapear from virtual path

Tags: iis-6

After I've configured GZIP on IIS 6 the web site was loaded very fast but the problem is that some images that are located in a virtual folder inside the IIS couldn't be viewed. even if the user writes the exact link to the image, the link doesn't work for him. I've removed GZIP and the images are working again. Has anyone ever configured GZIP and had problems like these?
Thanks

Comment: For all browsers, or just IE6? Try firefox, chrome, etc.

Comment: it happens in all browsers